# What is the best way to handle irregular nested object/arrays with Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, meteor, nested

I've some trouble finding an elegant and efficient way to handle irregular nested arrays/objects in nodeJS. By irregular I mean arrays/objects that can have 1, 2, 3 or more dimensions.

For example, 2 different cases :

First case :

```
"head": {
    "firstElement": {
        "Choice1": [
            "Some text",
            "some text"
        ],
        "Choice2": [
            "Some text",
            "Some text"
        ]
    },
    "SecondElement": [
        "Some text",
        "Some text"
    ]
}
```

Second case :

```
"head": {
    "firstElement": [
        "Some text",
        "Some text"
    ],
    "secondElement": [
        "Some text",
    ]
}
```

What I want is to be able to extract all of that, keep everything except the "Choices" I don't want and finally print it clearly in a div.

Expected :

```html
<div>
   <h1>FirstElement</h1>
       <h2>Choice#</h2>
           <p>Some text</p>
           <p>Some text</p>
   <h1>SecondElement</h1>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

The nested aspect in HTML isn't a problem, I'm just struggling with the algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve here... are you trying to render html that reflects the structure of your data?

Comment: Exactly but with post-processing on eventuals ```choices#``` and display it almost as it is (just convert the json form into ```<h1>```, ```<h2>```, ```<p>``` and so on. I tried to do it with ```Object.keys()``` and ```Object.values``` to get and store everything and print it with ```{{#with}}``` and ```{{#each}}```. But as the data is irregular it generate errors. Maybe I could do it by creating an Array of objects containing a key and the associated values and eventual nested keys/values and apply ```{{#each}}``` on it.

Comment: If you were using React I think it would be pretty easy to do. Never been big into Blaze so can't comment about that. You could always put in a React component to do it :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I’ve never used React for now but I’ll look into that, heard good stuff about it. I guess it’s time to learn ;) I’ll try to do it Blaze way but if it’s to messy I’ll try with React

Comment: At first I wasn't keen on React because it mashes up js and markup in the same file, but in fact it's a bonus, because you don't have a boundary between the two. Once you understand the syntax, you can devise anything you like - and I think it's what you need in this situation where you have a complex problem, and the templating system isn't flexible enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with arbitrary levels of depth is always a challenging task, especially when the structure (as in your examples) can additionally vary between types.

To tackle such a structure you could use a recursive template, which iterates the structure and either generates content or continues to scan down to the lowest level of children.

```html
<template name="recursive">
    {{#with data}}
        {{#if isString this}}
            <!--
            Print string values directly as paragraph.
            No recursion included.
            -->
            <p>{{this}}</p>
        {{else if isArray this}}
            <!--
            If we have an array f values then iterate
            and call a new template instance but don't 
            increase the level, since the values in the 
            array could also be just strings
            -->
            {{#each this}}
                {{> recursive data=this level=level}}
            {{/each}}
        {{else if isObject this}}
            <!--
            Now with an object we need to transform it into
            an iterable version, first (using the mapped helper).
            We also need to increase the level of nesting using incLevel.
            -->
            {{#each map in (mapped this)}}
                <!-- this is to keep the code more tidy and readable -->
                {{> headline level=level title=map.key}}
                {{> recursive data=map.value level=incLevel}}
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

For reasons of readability we can extract the logic to determine which headline we want to render into an own Template:

```
<template name="headline">
    {{#if level1 level}}
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{else if level2 level}}
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    {{else}}
        {{level}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Read the comments inside the Template's code for explanations on what happens there.

Now, because of the complexity of the intended rendering logic, we need some helpers to

- detect data types
- detect level of depth, increase level of depth
- map Object to iterable

```js
Template.recursive.helpers({
  mapped (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ key, value: obj[ key ] }))
  },
  level() {
    return Template.instance().data.level || 1
  },
  incLevel() {
    const level = Template.instance().data.level
    return level ? level + 1 : 2
  },
  isArray (element) {
    return Array.isArray(element)
  },
  isString (element) {
    return typeof element === 'string'
  },
  isObject (element) {
    return typeof element === 'object'
  }
})
```

Note, that the levels start with one, because your headlines also start with one.
Speaking of headlines, we also need helpers for the headline Template:

```js
Template.headline.helpers({
  level1(lvl) {
    return lvl === 1
  },
  level2(lvl) {
    return lvl === 2
  },
  // ... up to 6
  // then fallback to <strong> if lvl > 6
})
```

You can call the Template like this (note, that I placed it just as an example in the `<body>`):

```
<body>
{{> recursive data=example1}}
{{> recursive data=example2}}
</body>
```

Where the `example1` and `example2` are helpers, passing the data to your Template:

```
const example1 = {
  'head': {
    'firstElement': {
      'Choice1': [
        'Some text',
        'some text'
      ],
      'Choice2': [
        'Some text',
        'Some text'
      ]
    },
    'SecondElement': [
      'Some text',
      'Some text'
    ]
  }
}

const example2 = {
  'head': {
    'firstElement': [
      'Some text',
      'Some text'
    ],
    'secondElement': [
      'Some text',
    ]
  }
}

Template.body.helpers({
  example1() {
    return Object.values(example1)
  },
  example2() {
    return Object.values(example2)
  }
})
```

Now you may wonder why I did not include the following requirement:

> keep everything except the "Choices" I don't want

This is because with such a Template you already have fulfill a complex task:

- detect structure
- decide how to render content
- render content

Squeezing another responsibility into such a Template will literally blow your code (at some point, I assume your structures to be even more complex than in this example).

So what could you do to solve this problem?

- Make sure you only pass the data to the Template that will be rendered
- Let the "parent" Template handle the processing (removing unwanted choices), which is basically a task that can be achieved without Blaze as it mostly consists of find and filter.
- Keep anything out of this Template, that goes beyond rendering some given data.
- If still experiencing problems or having trouble with this encapsulated approach, please take a revision on the nested nature of the original data. Maybe you can normalize things to receive a more linear structured data in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Jankapunkt ! I thought about recursive template but didn’t want to do it since I was thinking an easier way existed. Filtering on field is important, I have to think about a solution that would work with it. I’ll see what I can do today !

Comment: Hi again, So I fixed my problem by changing the way I store the data. Instead of a potential deep nested array/object, I have an array of object containing one string and the other informations I need to group and display them.
It now looks like that (not ideal but it's working fine) :
```"Array": [
    {
        "value": "text1",
        "level": x,
        "variable": false/true (true if it's a #choice, depending on user selection),
        "text-type": "h5", "h6", "p" or other
        "parent": parent value (optional),
        "type": "type of data (optional),
    }
]```